# How do I arrange the navbar so that it is spaced out evenly?

Tags: html, css, navbar

I have tried to use the margin and padding tags, but I can never get it right because screen sizes change, and that makes the arrangements change. Also tried using flex

I am trying to make a navigation bar (top) in HTML and CSS, but I want to make all the  tags uniform in spacing so it looks nicer.
Right now it looks like this:
[image]

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div class="header">
  <div class="container">
      <h1 class="logo"></h1>
      <div class="nav">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="history.html">History</a></li>
          <li><a href="eat.html">Where to Eat</a></li>
          <li><a href="visit.html">Places to visit</a></li>
          <li><a href="nature.html">Beauties of Nature</a></li>
          <li><a href="nature.html">How to navigate Seoul</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
width: 80%;
margin: 0 auto;
}

.header {
background: #293380;
}

.header::after {
content: '';
display: table;
clear: both;
}

.logo {
float: left;
padding: 10px 0;
}

.nav {
float: right;
}

.nav ul {
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style: none;
}

.nav li {
flex: 1;
display: inline-block;
margin-left: 70px;
padding-top: 23px;

position: relative;
}

.nav a {
color: #F0EFF7;
text-decoration: none;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: 14px;
}

.nav a:hover {
color: #953D60;
}

.nav a::before {
content: '';
display: block;
height: 5px;
background-color: #F7D9F1;

position: absolute;
top: 0;
width: 0%;
```

Comment: check out the `justify-content` css attribute

Answer (score 0):

in your css file, under `.nav ul`, write `justify-content: space-between;`, which spaces all the elements evenly.

I really recommend you look further into `justify-content`, since its the main way to space out the content the way you want. Really good tool

Comment: Sorry didnt work.